# Azure Pipelines - Could not find service Error

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline which works fine in some of my projects. A created new organization and I wanted to use the pipeline there too. I copied the yaml code to the project, Setup a new pipeline, but I got an error and I don't know why.
The error throws in upload step.
I tried to change the step to PublishArtifact, but I got the same error.
Can somebody help me to find the solution?

**The pipeline error:**

```bash
Publish script

View raw log
Starting: Publish script
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish pipeline artifact
Description  : Publish a local directory or file as a named artifact for the current pipeline
Version      : 0.141.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact
==============================================================================
Uploading pipeline artifact from /home/vsts/work/1/a/120.zip for build #120
Using default max parallelism.
Max dedup parallelism: 192
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 725a7bc3-3a45-460a-b17e-d831db7982ed
DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 725a7bc3-3a45-460a-b17e-d831db7982ed
1 files processed.
Processed 1 files from /home/vsts/work/1/a successfully.
Uploading 1 files from directory /home/vsts/work/1/a.
Uploaded 62,099,157 out of 99,088,314 bytes.
Uploaded 72,077,736 out of 99,088,493 bytes
Content upload is done!

Content upload statistics:
Total Content: 198.2 MB
Physical Content Uploaded: 64.0 MB
Logical Content Uploaded: 72.1 MB
Compression Saved: 8.1 MB
Deduplication Saved: 126.1 MB
Number of Chunks Uploaded: 904
Total Number of Chunks: 4,772

ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session 725a7bc3-3a45-460a-b17e-d831db7982ed
##[error]Could not find service '2a313f99-f039-49a7-b2dd-792d5ddab990' from host'e66ad7ba-8f3a-416b-99f7-c791f17a2dce'. Please ensure the service is registered with the Shared Platform Service.
Finishing: Publish script
```

**My pipeline code**

```yaml
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '16.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'
    
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
    
    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Publish'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: test-env
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:            
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: narwhal-web-strapi'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'XXXX'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              appName: 'XXXXX'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|16-lts'
              startUpCommand: 'npm run start'
```

The error occurs in **upload** task.

What I tried:

- Change upload task to pubish and PublisArtifact
- Change to another working directory

I got the same error. The pipeline works fine in another organization. The organization has billing with one parallel MS hosted agent.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem while deploying a docker image to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). I generated the pipeline using the "Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service" template. However, it generated a pipeline config that is outdated. As far as I remember, the `upload` task was highlighted as deprecated.

#### Change the Upload & Download Task

I have solved the issue by replacing the upload and the download task. In the **build stage**, add the following task:

```
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

It publishes the complete working directory to Azure Pipelines (Container) store. The working directory looks like `/home/vsts/work/1/s` in the logs. You can verify the content of the directory with the `- script: ls -la` pipeline task.

Next, add a download task to the **deploy stage**:

```
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

It downloads the artifact folder name `drop` a single time and downloads it to the artifact directory. The artifact directory looks like `/home/vsts/work/1/a/drop`   in the logs. At this point, you can refer to the drop folder with `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/` in your pipeline file.

> Note: The `downloadType` and `downloadPath` are not necessary in this example because they specify their default values. Check the documentation for more details: [PublishBuildArtifacts@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines), [DownloadBuildArtifacts@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines)

#### An Example of AKS Deployment

For the sake of completeness let me share the whole pipeline to deploy docker images to AKS.

```
trigger: none

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
# -- snip secrets --
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: $(tag)
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: <my-environment>
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              itemPattern: '**/manifests/*.yml'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
          - task: KubernetesManifest@1
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
          - task: KubernetesManifest@1
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              manifests: |
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/manifests/deployment.yml
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/manifests/service.yml
              imagePullSecrets: $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
```

You can always use bash scripts for debugging purposes. For example `echo` variables values or `ls` a folder in the virtual machine.